# Obfuscating java versus .net applications, is it pretty much the same?

Tags: java, .net, obfuscation

When obfuscating your source code, are there any differences between Java and .NET web applications?

or is the resulting obfuscated .dlls/.jars pretty much the same?

Can you apply better obfuscating techniques in java versus .net, or again its the same pretty much?

(not looking to debate how obfuscation won't hide intellectual property etc., let's assume we all understand the scope of what obfuscation brings)

Answer (score 3):

Given the normal processes applied during obfuscation and the similarities in the code structure I think you'd be hard pressed to find one better than the other.